# Owl carousel navigation arrows on side

Tags: html, css

How do I get the prev and next button on top of the slider on the sides? Just like this: http://soledad.pencidesign.com/soledad-hipster/

This is how mine looks like right now http://testar.kashmaizat.se/

I'm using the Owl Carousel slider...

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".owl-carousel").owlCarousel({
   center:true, 
   items:2, 
   loop:true, 
   nav:true, 
   margin:10, 
   stagePadding: 20});
});
owl.on('mousewheel', '.owl-stage', function (e) {
    if (e.deltaY>0) {
        owl.trigger('next.owl');
    } else {
        owl.trigger('prev.owl');
    }
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

```html
<html>
    <head>

        <link href="http://testar.kashmaizat.se/wp-content/themes/ett/css/owl.theme.default.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
        <link href="http://testar.kashmaizat.se/wp-content/themes/ett/css/owl.carousel.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
        <link href="http://testar.kashmaizat.se/wp-content/themes/ett/css/owl.carousel.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

        <script src="http://testar.kashmaizat.se/wp-content/themes/ett/js/owl.carousel.js"></script>
        <script src="http://testar.kashmaizat.se/wp-content/themes/ett/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://testar.kashmaizat.se/wp-content/themes/ett/js/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://testar.kashmaizat.se/wp-content/themes/ett/js/jquery.mousewheel.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://testar.kashmaizat.se/wp-content/themes/ett/js/jquery.mousewheel.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="owl-carousel">
            <div>  
         <img src="http://kashmaizat.se/other/images/johannaflex.jpg" />
            </div>
            <div> 
         <img src="http://kashmaizat.se/other/images/flexsliderimg.jpg" /> 
            </div>
            <div> 
                <img src="http://kashmaizat.se/other/images/flexsliderimgtwo.jpg" /> 
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One way to go about this would be to set position: relative for the main slideshow container (that contains all of the slideshow elements). Then, make .owl-prev and .owl-next position: absolute; and define your parameters from there. So for instance, you will want .owl-prev to be left:0; and .owl-next to be right:0; Then, use a negative value for the top property of each.

You would want to set position: relative for the main container so that it is relative to its normal positioning in the DOM. Then, position absolute for the elements contained inside of the main container is absolute to that container, which allows you to position them more specifically.

In summary:

```
    .your-slideshow-container-class {
      position:relative;
    }

    .owl-prev, .owl-next {
        position:absolute;
     }

    .owl-prev {
        left:0;
        top: 200px;
     }

     .owl-next {
        right:0;
        top:200px;
     }
```

I hope this helps! :)